# how to add $(document).click event to plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Where is the correct place to add this $(document).click event in my custom plugin?

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {



       $(document).click(function (event) {  // where do I add this?


         alert('this id was clicked');

       });




        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));



$('#a,#b,#c').greenify({
        // My settings goes here
    });
```

Comment: Does it matter if `$().greenify()` has been called yet?

Comment: but `this.click(function() {})` instead of `document`?

Comment: it's not clear for me what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care if `$(selector).greenify()` has been called yet, you can place it in with your plugin declaration:

```
;(function($){
  $(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
      alert('hello, world! (from greenify)');
    });
  });
  $.fn.extend({
    greenify: function(opts){
      // continue with plugin
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Just keep in mind that no matter if `.greenify` is used, this click event is bound and listenining.

if you want it done only when `.greenify` is used, you can do something like:

```
;(function($){
  var greenifyClick = false;
  $.fn.extend({
    greenify: function(opts){
      if (!greenifyClick){
        greenifyClick = $(document).click(function(){
          alert('hello, world! (from greenify)');
        });
      }
      // continue with plugin
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This would make it bind if/when `.greenify` is used, but only once.

Answer (score 0):

You are attacking this wrong. The plugin itself should not wait for the document to load.

In your script (not the plugin), you have the document ready and call the plugin when you like. Always let the user decide. The plugin itself should be as fluid as possible and callable when the user wants it.

Plugin

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Main js-file

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $(elm).greenify({
        // My settings goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .... but I need to bind a click event to the document from my plugin once when the plugin initializes.